# UnSupported Media Type Create Websites IIS Manager 2.0 API

Tags: c#, .net, rest, iis

I trying to create an website using IIS Administration API, but i received this error al crearlo: 
https://image.prntscr.com/image/I_ZnpChkTjeAvadEGCVOvA.png

This is my code:

```
  var apiClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
              .Accept
              .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        // Set access token for every request
        apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Access-Token", $"Bearer {ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Token"]}");
        var res = apiClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:55539/api/webserver/websites", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {

            name = website.Name,
            physical_path = $"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Sites\\{website.name}",
            bindings = new []
            {
                new
                {
                    protocol = "HTTP",
                    port = "80",
                    ip_addres = "*"
                }
            },
            application_pool= new
            {
                id = "DefaultAppPool"
            }

        }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```

Example:

```
{
"name": "Demonstration Site",
"physical_path": "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\DemonstrationSite",
"bindings": [
    {
        "protocol": "HTTP",
        "port": "8081",
        "ip_address": *
    }
],
"application_pool": {
    "id": {application_pool_id}
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your JSON request object? I suspect JSON request may have errors..

Comment: why the application_pool_id is not being replaced in your JSON?

Comment: try removing this line of code apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
              .Accept
              .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));